# In arrray multiple object need to megre a single with value of sum using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, merge, sum

I have a result of an array which contain numbers of array objects, and i need to merge the result in single array with unique value of `content` and value of sum `total` like below desired result. Helps are definitely appreciated

> Result Set

```
[
  [
    {
      content: 'Aqurie',
      total: 5
    },
    {
      content: 'Mail function',
      total: 4
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      content: 'Aqurie',
      total: 4
    },
    {
      content: 'Mail function',
      total: 10
    }
  ]
]
```

> Desired Result

```
[
  {
    content: 'Aqurie',
    total: 9
  },
  {
    content: 'Mail function',
    total: 14
  }
]
```

My current implementation attempts to do something like this:

```
var transformed = arr.reduce(function(a, b){ return a.concat(b); });
console.log(transformed );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following if the order will be same in all nested array

```js
var arr = [
  [{
    content: 'Aqurie',
    total: 5
  }, {
    content: 'Mail function',
    total: 4
  }],
  [{
    content: 'Aqurie',
    total: 4
  }, {
    content: 'Mail function',
    total: 10
  }]
];

// reduce function for merging the array
var res = arr.reduce(function(a, b) {
  // iterating the array for updating total 
  var ret = a.map(function(v, i) {
    v.total += b[i].total;
    // returning updated object
    return v;
  });
  // returning merged array
  return ret;
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(res, null, 3) + '</pre>');
```

---

**UPDATE 1 :** If the order is random then add an additional for loop inside `map()` and check for element by comparing `content` property

```js
var arr = [
  [{
    content: 'Aqurie',
    total: 5
  }, {
    content: 'Mail function',
    total: 4
  }],
  [{
    content: 'Mail function',
    total: 10
  }, {
    content: 'Aqurie',
    total: 4
  }]
];

// reduce method to merge the array
var res = arr.reduce(function(a, b) {
  // iterating over inner array and updating total value based on content
  var ret = a.map(function(v) {
    // for loop for finding matched array index
    for (i1 = 0; i1 < b.length; i1++) {
      // checking content 
      if (v.content == b[i1].content) {
        // if matched updating the total value
        v.total += b[i1].total;
        // breking the for loop on match
        break;
      }
    }
    // returning updated array
    return v;
  });
  // returning merged array
  return ret;
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(res, null, 3) + '</pre>');
```

---

**UPDATE 2 :**
The above method will not work in certain cases , which only update the total of first array values. For ex :-  if second array contains other content then that will skip.

```js
var arr = [
  [{
    content: 'Aqurie',
    total: 5
  }],
  [{
    content: 'Mail function',
    total: 10
  }, {
    content: 'Aqurie',
    total: 4
  }],
  [{
    content: 'other',
    total: 4
  }]

];

// reduce method to merge the array
var res = arr.reduce(function(a, b) {
  // iterating over inner array and updating total value based on content
  b.forEach(function(v) {
    // for loop for finding matched array index
    var found = false;
    for (i1 = 0; i1 < a.length; i1++) {
      // checking content 
      if (v.content == a[i1].content) {
        found = true;
        // if matched updating the total value
        a[i1].total += v.total;
        // breking the for loop on match
        break;
      }
    }
    // pushing element if new element found
    if (!found)
      a.push(v);
  });
  return a;
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(res, null, 3) + '</pre>');
```

---

Comment: pranav, OP's requirement is totally different than what you have answered.

Comment: @PranavCBalan I have dynamic value of an array i don't use this function with static approach

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
function flattenAndSum(arr){
  var newArr = [];
  var existing;
  arr.forEach(function(itm){
    itm.forEach(function(inner){
      existing = findIt(inner,newArr);
      if(existing){
        existing.total += inner.total;
      } else {
         newArr.push(inner);
      }
    });
  });

  return newArr;
}

function findIt(obj,newArr){
 for(var i=0;i<newArr.length;i++) {
   if(newArr[i].content === obj.content){
     return newArr[i];
   }
 }
}

console.log(flattenAndSum(arr));
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/6bjL372z/)